# How do I get parameter from other parameters of same constructors (java)

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, identify

So I was supposed to identify a parameter based on other parameters of same constructor, for example:

```
public Student(String n, int sN, int hN){
    this.name = n;
    this.streetNum = sN;
    this.houseNum = hN;
}
```

The main class will be provided with all the parameters filled like this,

```
Student a = new Student("Abigail", 1, 5);
```

so I need to figure out how to find the the name "Abigail" from streetNum 1 and houseNum 5 of students as given.

Comment: So these Students are in an array or list?

Comment: They are in an array

Comment: and you have to loop through the students and find the one matching some criteria ?

Comment: yes, but they are in string form, like String.format("name" in  house "houseNumber")

Comment: These comments may suggest that you need to add info to you question as it is not well defined, or better still, post an [MCVE]

Comment: You should consider upvoting answers that are useful in helping you, downvoting ones that aren't, and accept the ones that solve your problem(s). You've asked five questions in about one day and not a single one has an accepted answer. Not doing so makes you sort of like a parasite and people will pass on helping you when they see that in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a utility class that does that with a method that takes the attributes and the array of students. Additional checks may be required.

```
public class Students {
    public static String findStudentName(int sN, int hN, Student[] students) {
        for (Student s : students) {
            if (s.getSN() == sN && s.getHN() == hN) {
                return s.getName();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code will return the *first* student's name with matching attributes or null otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can include below method in your Student Class

```
public static Student getStudent(Student[] students, String sName, int streetNum, int houseNum) {
    for (Student student : students) {
        if (sName.equals(student.getName()) && student.getStreetNum() == streetNum
                && student.getHouseNum() == houseNum) {
            return student;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and acccess it like below

```
Student[] students = ...// student array
Student s = Student.getStudent(students, "Abigail", 1, 5);
System.out.println(s != null ? s.getName() : "No match found");
```